# How can I edit the granularity of location data(lon, lat)

Tags: geolocation, location

Lets say I have a location -44.1321, 50.3145 representing at a street level. What would the edited version be to represent it at a city level?

And also, what defines the granularity in the data? thanks.

Comment: 4 decimal places (0.0001) equates to 11.132 m at the equator ie individual street .

Comment: so if i remove one more decimal, 0.001 it is 100m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of decimal places required for a particular precision for latitude & longitude at the equator is:

```
decimal places  at equator  
1.0             111.32 km   
0.1              11.132 km  
0.01              1.1132 km     
0.001           111.32 m    
0.0001           11.132 m   
0.00001           1.1132 m  
0.000001        111.32 mm   
0.0000001        11.132 mm  
0.00000001        1.1132 mm
```

As you moves away from the equator towards a pole the longitude distance decreases as it approaches the pole.

The longitude distance can be calculated by multiplying the latitude distance by the cosine of the longitude.

```
ie at 45degree  1.1132 m * cos(45)
                = 0.00001* 0.707
                = 0.7871 m
```

Comment: thanks! can i cask a quick question regarding capture of GPS data. Does a GPS device always capture at the finest level, and the application will decide the granularity, or is it individual depending on the device?

Comment: @vasper 
Depending on device and whither GPS, wifi or  Cellular positioning.GPS  ~1-10 meters, wifi ~!0% of GPS , Cellular positioning ~ !00% of GPS